# ReactJS simple app won't render

Tags: reactjs

I tried this simple ReactJS app and it won't render anything.
I'm using atom as my text editor.

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <script src="https://fb/.me/react-15.1.0.js"></script>
  <script src="https://fb/.me/react-dom-15.1.0.js"></script>
  <script crossorigin src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-
  core/5.8.38/browser-polyfill.min.js"></script>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Hello World with React</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="react-container"></div>
  <script type="text/babel" src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

script.js

```
const { render } = ReactDOM;

render(
    <h1 id='title'
        className='header'
        style={{backgroundColor: 'orange', color: 'white', fontFamily: 
        'verdana'}}>
    Hello World
    </h1>,
    document.getElementById('react-container')
);
```

file structure

```
reactapp
    -index.html
    -script.js
```

please correct me if i'm using an older version of ReactJS or if there is anything wrong in script.js file.

I tried thin in plunker and it showed some errors in script.js file

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RMVSm.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A couple of things that I've noticed. Usually you would require the react and react-dom libraries when transpiling with Babel:

```
const React = require('react');
const {render} = require('react-dom');
```

Or when using import statements:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM, {render} from "react-dom";
```

But the way plunker and other code editors work is a bit different. I couldn't get it to work in plunker either for some reason, but check out the same in CodePen: https://codepen.io/Jeff518Code/pen/zRwqzj

Also make sure that you quote the style properties (I've done so in CodePen)

```
<h1 id='title' className='header' style={{'backgroundColor': 'orange', 'color': 'white', 'fontFamily': 'Verdana'}}>
```

Comment: this works fine in codepen but i copied exact code into my ide and it didnt work. that is pretty strange. However i changed react js and babel references as in @HarshMakadia 's answer and it worked fine.

Comment: Hmm, can you tell me what the error is that you're getting? That might go a long way. It actually gets easier when you have React setup with a module bundler like Webpack, Gulp + Browserify + Babelify. I can help you out with some boilerplate for that if you are interested.

Comment: It did not show any errors on the console. It just did not render any html from js. I know that this is not he professional way to do this. So i used npm and the command create-react-app to build all the configurations for me. I guess this is the best way to do it so that i can focus on actual development. thank you for the reply

Comment: Sure. That is a good idea. Pretty much whatever you end up doing in Plnkr or CodePen is bad practice, it gets you used to setting things up a certain way and then you're wondering why something doesn't work when you get to a real dev environment. Video learning sites do this a bit too much IMHO. Especially with React, you want to get to setting up your dev environment and pick your toolchain ASAP. Also, ignore most of the "old style" examples with React.createClass. It's pulling away from ES6/7+

Answer (score 0):

Try this minimal HTML template for Reactjs. Hope this is useful to you.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>Hello World</title>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6.15.0/babel.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="root"></div>
    <script type="text/babel">

      ReactDOM.render(
        <h1>Hello, world!</h1>,
        document.getElementById('root')
      );

    </script>
    <!--
      Note: this page is a great way to try React but it's not suitable for production.
      It slowly compiles JSX with Babel in the browser and uses a large development build of React.

      To set up a production-ready React build environment, follow these instructions:
      * https://reactjs.org/docs/add-react-to-a-new-app.html
      * https://reactjs.org/docs/add-react-to-an-existing-app.html

      You can also use React without JSX, in which case you can remove Babel:
      * https://reactjs.org/docs/react-without-jsx.html
      * https://reactjs.org/docs/cdn-links.html
    -->
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use the babel-standalone source.
change from:

```
<script crossorigin src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-core/5.8.38/browser-polyfill.min.js"></script>
```

to

```
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-standalone/6.21.1/babel.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: did not work. console says "[Deprecation] Resource requests whose URLs contained both removed whitespace (`\n`, `\r`, `\t`) characters and less-than characters (`<`) are blocked. Please remove newlines and encode less-than characters from places like element attribute values in order to load these resources. See https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5735596811091968 for more details."

Comment: Sorry for I forgot a quotes sign in the code. I have edited my answer.